# get the id of span when input text is clicked

Tags: jquery

Hi all i need to get the value of the inputbox and span tag attribute class , when the anchor tag is clicked. both of them are in the corresponding li. Can we use li index method to get the info we required.?

click

click

Comment: Did you try anything??Show what you are try

Comment: ye it worked $('li a.clickme').click(function(){    
  alert($(this).next('span').attr('class'));
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li a.clickme').click(function(){    
  alert($(this).next('span').attr('class'));
})
```

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Ep9F9/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
     $(this).next().attr('class');

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery .click function

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $(this).next().attr("class");
});
```